# how can i generate randome number using replace function javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

i'm new to javascript i need to generate random number using replace it is possible i try

```
function generateUUID() {
    var dt = new Date().getTime()
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace('/[xy]/g', function (c) {
        var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0
        dt = Math.floor(dt / 16)
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16)
    })
    return uuid
}
```

this function always return `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`
What am i missing ?

Comment: does the string `'/[xy]/g'` exist? no ... you want a regular expression ... `/[xy]/g`

Comment: use regular expression format properly `/[xy]/g`  instead of `'/[xy]/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You're using a string rather than a RegExp in the replace function, this should be a simple fix, e.g. just change

```
.replace('/[xy]/g',
```

to

```
.replace(/[xy]/g,
```

```js
function generateUUID() {
    var dt = new Date().getTime()
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0
        dt = Math.floor(dt / 16)
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16)
    })
    console.log("uuid",uuid)
    return uuid
}

console.log(generateUUID())
```

I'd also suggest looking at third-party libraries for this purpose, [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for example, it uses cryptographically-strong random values.

```js
function generateUUID() {
    return uuid.v4();
}
console.log(generateUUID());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uuid/8.3.2/uuid.min.js" integrity="sha512-UNM1njAgOFUa74Z0bADwAq8gbTcqZC8Ej4xPSzpnh0l6KMevwvkBvbldF9uR++qKeJ+MOZHRjV1HZjoRvjDfNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @Terry Lennox

Comment: No problem, glad to be of some help!